# Find all $(x,y)$ such that $\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}$ is continuous at $(0,0)$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

[image]

We **want:**

$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\dfrac{x^2+xy+y^2}{x^2+y^2}=1$$

It is not immediately evident to me how to factor this, and in fact I don't think we can, but something I **see is that, if we were to somehow "remove" the $xy$ term on the numerator**, then our numerator and denominator would become the same, and hence the limit would go to $1$

I think the answer is: $\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2|x=0\text{ or } y=0\}$

I haven't really shown any math steps, but I think this is correct?

Comment: I do not understand why you want to find $(x,y)$ if already $(x,y) \rightarrow (0,0)$ :/

Comment: Let me post the original question, one second

Comment: Has the original question made what I'm trying to say more clearer?

Comment: Use polar coordinates $x = r \cos \theta, y = r \sin \theta$ and consider the limit $r \to 0$.

Comment: @Mr.Chip, I used polar, and I see that the $r$ actually cancel out, and so we are only left with a limit in terms of $\theta$, so this would mean that the limit does not exist at (0,0), but it doesnt tell me anything about the values of $x,y$?

Comment: Now you can conclude the limit exists everywhere *except* (0,0), because everywhere else it's given by a ratio of polynomials whose denominator does not vanish.

Comment: @Mr.Chip, oh okay makes sense, so in my answer, I would write, "The limit at (0,0) does not exist, as it depends on $\theta$, but everywhere else, the denominator does not vanish (it still has an $r$), and so it is continous everywhere else"

Comment: Well, kind of. Everywhere else you don't need to talk about $r$. You're only involving $r$ when considering what happens at $(0,0)$. So your statement is correct without the comment about $r$.

Comment: Well the question specifically asks for (x,y) so that $f$ is continous at $0,0$, but clearly there is no such $x,y$

Comment: The problem makes no sense as stated. Please correct the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$f$ is discontinuous at $(0,0)$. Take $y=mx$ and take the limit $x\to 0$. The limit depends on $m$, hence the limit $(x,y)\to (0,0)$ does not exists.

Answer (score 2):

Hint $$ f(x,x) = 3/2$$
Thus your function cannot be continuous at (0,0). but f is continuous everywhere else as ratio of non vanishing polynomial.